# How use angular-localize module with grunt-locales

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization

I am trying to use the [angular-localize](https://github.com/blueimp/angular-localize) together with [grunt-locales](https://github.com/blueimp/grunt-locales).

I have followed the steps on both repositories by:

- Installing both using npm and bower
- Adding the tasks and watch to Gruntfile (needed for grunt-locales)
- Imported the `.js` at my `index.html` (needed for angular-localize)
- Added the the module to my project `angular.module('localize')`
- Added the tags `localize` at my HTML tags
- Run commands `grunt locales:update` and `grunt locales:update`.

What I have observed is that the `i18n.js` generated apparently are not automatically loaded and the variable `window.i18n` is `undefined`.

What am I missing to do to make the module work?